# how sort string value [3,2,10,1/k,1.1/k] to [1/k,1.1/k,2,3,10] by php

Tags: php, sorting

I have array value `[3,2,10,1/k,1.1/k]` 
I need to sort array to `[1/k,1.1/k,2,3,10]`
If you have better way, please tell me.

Comment: What you have tried till yet?

Comment: A better way than what?

Comment: sorry my english language. I forget tell about natsort. it not work.

Comment: What was the output when you ran it?

Comment: natsort[3,2,10,'1/k','1.1/k'] = ['1.1/k','1/k',2,3,10]
i want ['1/k','1.1/k',2,3,10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sort`, but with parameter `"SORT_NUMERIC"`:

```
$my_array = [3, 2, 10, '1/k', '1.1/k'];
sort($my_array, SORT_NUMERIC );
print_r($my_array);
```